# Where is the speed dial on a new tab in Firefox 60?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

The speed dial is not shown anymore when opening a new tab in Firefox 60. The old speed dial had a search box, icons of top sites, recently visited webpages and snippets from Mozilla on it. How to get the speed dial new tab in Firefox back?

Comment: try about:newtab. If it works, set it as your startup page from options -> Home Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `about:config` and set the Value of `browser.newtabpage.enabled` to `true`.

Comment: Good find, but I would be rather curious to know how yours was set to `false` in the first place.  That definitely isn't the default configuration.

Comment: @Run5k - indeed, false is not the default. But even set to "true", the new look of the new tab page is far from a speed dial, as it only has two rows. I will add an answer on how to change that.

Comment: @cipricus , while I certainly appreciate the feedback, my intent wasn't to start a discussion regarding what is or isn't a "speed dial" within Firefox.  For the benefit of future readers, I was trying to emphasize that this is *not* a problem they will normally see.  It was changed on this specific machine, either manually by the end-user or by installing an add-on that modified it.

Comment: @cipricus My speed dial has three rows, not two rows by default and the default speed dial settings can also be changed by following your instructions. My speed dial is bigger than the screen so I have to scroll down to see the third row.

Answer (score 0):

The setting to `false` is not the default in Ff 60. But even set to `true`, as indicated in the other answer, the new look of the new tab page is a bit far from a speed dial, as it only has two rows. It is not even called a speed dial in fact, it is a new tab page with different categories: Search, Top Sites, Highlights and Snippets. But the Top Sites category can be changed so that it has more rows, the other categories can be removed. The latter can be done from the new page gear button to the top right.

[image]

The number of rows  in Top Sites category can be increased to make it look more like a speed dial by going to `about:config` and searching for **browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.topSitesRows**, where the number can be increased.

As I cannot recommend a speed dial add-on that I do not consider buggy and/or bloated, this is my solution for Firefox 60, although I must admit it falls behind the default speed dial Opera has.